# Android matching the camera picture size to a phone's screen size

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, hardware, screen

I've an app that takes a camera shot and saves the jpeg on the sdcard. When i load the jpeg it is much larger than the screen. how can i display the picture to the same size as the screen as it looked in the camera preview? i've written code to get the hardware's screensize in pixels and i've logged out the camera's available picture sizes eg

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();


       int w = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int h = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        Log.e(TAG, "*********** hardware screen height size = "+ h);
        Log.e(TAG, "*********** hardware screen width size = "+ w);

        for(int i = 0; i<sizes.size();i++){
            int height;
            int width;
            Camera.Size cs = (Size) sizes.get(i);
            height = cs.height;
            width = cs.width;
            Log.e(TAG, "*********** camera picsize = "+ height +" X " +width);
        }

    }
```

output:

```
07-18 20:59:37.567: ERROR/CameraTest(4394): *********** hardware screen height size = 480
07-18 20:59:37.567: ERROR/CameraTest(4394): *********** hardware screen width size = 320
07-18 20:59:37.572: ERROR/CameraTest(4394): *********** camera picsize = 1536 X 2048
07-18 20:59:37.572: ERROR/CameraTest(4394): *********** camera picsize = 1200 X 1600
07-18 20:59:37.577: ERROR/CameraTest(4394): *********** camera picsize = 768 X 1024
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved:**

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = Camera.open();

        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();


        int w = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int h = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


        try{
        params.setPictureSize(h, w);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
```